# Use "." to access the object in HTML part and use "[]" in JavaScript part?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it works in this way but I don't know why it works in this way. Please see the code below. So, why we use `"."` to access an object in HTML part and use `"[]"` to access an object in JavaScript part? Thanks.

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
        <span>{{detail.numbers.length}}</span> <!-- Output: 1, 2, 3 -->
        <!-- Won't work: <span>{{details[detail].numbers.length}}</span> -->
    </div>
</div>

angular.module("testApp", []).controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{"numbers": [1]}, {"numbers": [2, 2]}, {"numbers": [3, 3, 3]}];
    for (var detail in $scope.details) {
        console.log($scope.details[detail].numbers.length); //Output: 1, 2, 3
        //Won't work: console.log(detail.numbers.length);
    }
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/d5yL8ydk/18/.

Right click and inspect the page to see `console.log()` results.

Comment: You aren't using a `.` in angular, you are using `in`

Comment: You can check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/2565294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets and usually used along with the index of item in an array and If you want to access the items via index, use this version of ng-repeat

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,detail) in details">
        <span>{{detail.numbers.length}}</span> 
        <span>{{details[k].numbers.length}}</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

k will be the `key`,which is the index of each item returned by the `ng-repeat`

When you execute your for loop, the  iterator initialization/variable expression value will be the index, not the item from the array. To access each item in a loop, you can use the `angular.forEach` method, which will pass an item in the array to the callback.

```
$scope.details = [{"numbers": [1]}, {"numbers": [2, 2]}, {"numbers": [3, 3, 3]}];

angular.forEach($scope.details, function(detail, key) {
     console.log(detail.numbers.length);
     // or 
     console.log($scope.details[key].numbers.length);
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qefoti/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: Thanks! What can I do if I want to use "detail.numbers.length" in JavaScript?

Comment: length is a native property on array in javascript  and you should be able to access it

Comment: "console.log(detail.numbers.length)" will throw an error: detail.number is undefined. And "console.log(detail) in that "for loop" will output "0, 1, 2", which are the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Your example data has an array of objects.  The discrepancy you are describing has to do with how angular handles array iteration vs how JavaScript `in` works.

In Angular, arrays of objects are iterated through by returning the object for each iteration.  By contrast, the `in` operator returns the array index of each iteration. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

In the HTML, you can use an alternate syntax for `ng-repeat` which will return the index for each iteration, i.e. `"ng-repeat = (index, detail) in details"`.  Alternately, you can use the `$index` parameter that is automatically generated by angular, if the array is static.

In JavaScript, the Angular framework provides an iterator function that works similarly to `ng-repeat`, which will return the object for each iteration.

```
angular.forEach($scope.details, function(detail){
  console.log(detail.numbers.length);
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach